# Joomla K2 custom image sizes for items

Tags: image, joomla, joomla-k2

I want to make few more image resizing for K2 items in order to have custom image sizes to pull off in template like S, L, XL.

By that I wish to use more image sizes in my template.

I would end up with image_S, image_L, image_XL, image_CUSTOM, image_CUSTOM2 etc. perfect for me to use in template.

Joomla version 2.5.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

K2 has 5 sizes PER category by default. Do you need more than 5 sizes in any one particular category? Since the sizes that K2 generates can be configured per category you could have 5x number of category different images sizes without having to touch the core code. This would save you a lot of problems when you upgrade K2.